# Spring MVC ISO-8859-1 - Latin Capital Letter being inserted in response

Tags: java, spring, iso-8859-1

We are encountering a very strange scenario where we have a server setup using spring mvc, a response string is being written out with ISO-8859-1 encoding that includes unicode characters: "\u0095\u0086"

When the response gets read in the client using the same ISO-8859-1 encoding for some reason the response has an extra Latin Capital Letter inserted between the 2 unicode characters: "\u0095\u00C2\u0086"

Can anyone help explain why this happening and a potential fix for this?

Comment: Is the client a browser ? If yes: did you try multiple ones if which are affected by this problem ? Perhaps it might make sense to show us a network trace of the headers passed between server and client (F12 in a browser will do)